# Is force of impact experienced by an object a net force or a normal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, mass, collision

Suppose an object of mass $\rm m$ is released from a height $\rm h$ bounces off the ground and returns to a height $\rm h' (h'< h)$. The object experiences a force at the moment when it strikes the ground. Is this force a net force $\rm (N-mg)$ or the normal force by the ground. Sometimes given the above situation we are asked to find the average force between the ground and the object but why is the force called average?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit unclear, but I think you are referring to the **impulsive force** at the collision. Impulsive force is given by Newton's second law of motion $F=\frac {\Delta mv}{t}$ , whereas $t$ is the contact time and $\Delta mv $ is the change in the momentum. These impulsive forces are *massive* with respect to the weight of the object. And it is called as an **average** force because at the collision, $F$ changes with time (this time is infinitesimally small).

[image]

---

Note: In the graph, *force* is referred to the *impulsive force* (don't mind that $N$), and the *impulse* is the change in the momentum.

Answer (score 0):

When the object hits the ground, it gets a change in momentum. This change of momentum is caused by an impulse applied by the ground. Impulse is force times time. The force depends om the time the object is in contact with the ground. It depends on the acceleration the object gets.